# What are the biggest selling points of MOSS 2007 over WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, sharepoint-2007

I have to give a presentation to a client who is interested in SharePoint. My experience is primarily with MOSS 2007. I have customized and developed sites on MOSS 2007 but haven't had much time to play with WSS 3.0. The client wants an idea of which product would be suitable for their needs. At the moment, their needs center around document access, sharing and management. They also need a public facing website. On top of that, they want to know what other cool things they can do with SharePoint.

Besides information posted on [Microsoft website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePointtechnology/fx101758691033.aspx), what else would you suggest I make mention of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several MS links a great help when discussing with management.  The case studies allowed me to create a list of some key features that I could match to corporate goals/needs.

http://blogs.msdn.com/brittog/archive/2007/01/03/office-sharepoint-server-2007-case-studies.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/05/03/top-17-case-studies-for-microsoft-office-sharepoint-server-2007-and-several-new-moss-based-web-sites.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that WSS is free whereas MOSS is not. There are several advantages. The most important are publishing feature/template and **Shared Service Provider** that gives you 100s of new things to do. This is not there in WSS.

http://www.ekhichdi.com/e/INCREASE-THE-SAVE-AS-TEMPLATE-SIZE-9.html